# XSL table text on multiple lines

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

In the following code I am trying to get the value from a XML tag and put in a table in a PDF file. My problem is when the text from the tadig-raex-21:Description is too long, the text overflows the table and is not visible anymore. What I need is when the text is that long to have it on multiple lines. Any suggestion on how to do this? Many thanks

```
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="fontForAllDocumentAlignLeft" border-top="1pt solid black" border-bottom="1pt solid black">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./tadig-raex-21:Description"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200201/post80920.html

For everyone who will be in the same situation, what I did is that I inserted a zero-width space "&#200b;" between all words from my tadig-raex-21:Description using a replace function.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what `fontForAllDocumentAlignLeft` defines, I can only guess that you need to add `keep-together.within-column="always"` on the table cell.